# Go gRPC on Docker on Cloud Run "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp : i/o timeout""

Tags: docker, http2, google-cloud-run, grpc-go

I have a gRPC server

```
type Server struct {
    name         string
    host         string
    port         string
    dbUser       string
    dbPassword   string
    dbURL        string
    dbParameters string
}

func main() {

    /*Start of config*/
    server := Server{
        "User service",
        "",
        os.Getenv("PORT"),
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
    }
    /*End of config*/

    log.Printf("Starting: %s RPCServer\n", server.name)
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", server.host+":"+server.port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to liste: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        err = lis.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to close listener: %v\n", err)
        }
    }()
    gRPCServer := grpc.NewServer()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    reg := codecs.Register(bson.NewRegistryBuilder()).Build()
    mongoURI := options.Client().ApplyURI(
        "mongodb+srv://" + server.dbUser + ":" + server.dbPassword + "@" + server.dbURL + server.dbParameters,
    )

    mongoClient, err := mongo.NewClient(mongoURI, &options.ClientOptions{
        Registry: reg,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to create new mongo clinet: %s\n", err)
    }
    err = mongoClient.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect to db: %s\n", err)
    }

    /*Start of registering service*/
    authService, err := AuthService.NewAuthService()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to create server: %s\n", err)
    }
    s := UserService.NewServer(authService, mongoClient)
    UserService.RegisterUserServiceServer(gRPCServer, &s)
    /*End of registering service*/

    go func() {
        if err := gRPCServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to serve: %v\n", err)
        }
    }()
    log.Printf("server successfully started on port: %s\n\n", server.port)
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    <-c
    log.Printf("\nstopping server...\n")
    gRPCServer.Stop()
    err = lis.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to close listner: %s\n", err)
    }
    err = mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to disconnect from mongodb: %s\n", err)
    }
    log.Printf("successfully closed server\n")
}
```

And my Dockerfile is

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN cd /app && go build Main/server.go

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/server /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/Config/* /app
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=cred.json

EXPOSE 50051
CMD ["./server"]
```

I put up the docker image on Google Container Registry, and tried to use Cloud Run to run it using the following command

```
gcloud run deploy grpc-server-streaming\
          --project=project-id\
          --platform=managed\
          --region=asia-south1\
          --image=image-tag\
          --allow-unauthenticated
```

After which I went into Cloud Run application and enabled HTTP/2 connections. But am still not able to connect to the service. I get the following error

```
2021/04/21 17:04:36 rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

I've been stuck at this for two days and am not sure what to do.

Comment: The error looks like a failure in the proxy (Envoy), due to connection problems (connection termination). There's unfortunately no much to see from just this error message, and there are multiple possible reasons for it.

I would try to turn on logs on the server side, and try to find out whether the server is actually running, and if it has any errors.

Comment: Yea that is the issue but I'm not able to figure out what the issue is, so I deleted it and tried doing it again from scratch and it worked but I don't know why it did not work before, and I'm worried that when I will be deploying other services I might face the same issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same is happening for my ASPNet hosted gRPC service. It was working last Friday (2021-04-30), but on Monday (2021-05-03) I started getting this error message.
I have been searching for days, like you, for an answer. Thank-you to @menghanl for the `Envoy` pointer, I will open that can of worms.

@Chandraaditya Have a look at your Cloud Run Service's Logs to see if your service is actually being triggered.
I can see my service handling the request at the time I am getting the error. The gRPC service call appears to be 200 OK, but "Envoy" is not sending it back to the client.

[image]

Comment: So I don't know what I did but it ended up working but I'm not sure why. I deleted all the services linked to it and created them from scratch, but yea I figured it has something to do with how Cloud Run is calling the service, and I'm new to cloud services so it was so frustrating. I will update you on on this in the near future as I will be deploying a few more services. But thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @Chandraaditya did you delete the project? or just the Cloud Run Service? I will try making a new Cloud Run Service based on your reply above - thank you for that.

Comment: Turns out my gRPC service was NOT being called - in the Cloud Run Service's logs I was seeing the request coming in to Envoy?
I updated my service to `Console.WriteLine`, which goes to stdout to confirm that the service was doing something - it wasn't...
The gRPC service works fine when running locally in docker, and when 'debugging' in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yup that’s essentially the issue. And I just deleted the service and created a new cloud run survive. I also think the that it was caused by me having cloud built running, I think my continues deploy configuration on cloud run was not configuring those things automatically and so was not calling the service.